# Trying to create a 24 hour timer that resets itself

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

This is the code I have. Very messy, but due to my inexperience I can't detect why it does not work. By my counts the Decrements are js standard, at least for the milliseconds, seconds and minutes, not sure about the hours.

Here's the code. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<span id="tHours"></span>:<span id="tMins"></span>:<span id="tSeconds"></span>:<span id="tMilli"></span>

<script>
    var hours = 1;
    var mins = hours * 60;
    var secs = mins * 60;
    var mill = secs * 100;
    var currentHours = 0;
    var currentSeconds = 0;
    var currentMinutes = 0;
    vas currentMilli = 0;
    setTimeout('DecrementMilli()',100);
    setTimeout('DecrementSeconds()',1000);
    setTimeout('DecrementMinutes()',10000);
    setTimeout('DecrementHours()',100000);

    function DecrementMilli() {
        currentMilli = secs % 100;
        if(currentMilli <= 99) currentMilli = "000" + currentMilli;
        secs--;
        document.getElementById("tMilli").innerHTML = currentMilli; 
        if(mill !== -1) setTimeout('Decrement()',100);
    }
        function DecrementSeconds() {
        currentSeconds = secs % 60;
        if(currentSeconds <= 9) currentSeconds = "0" + currentSeconds;
        secs--;
        document.getElementById("tSeconds").innerHTML = currentSeconds; 
        if(secs !== -1) setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
    }
        function DecrementMinutes() {
        currentMinutes = Math.round(secs / 60);
        if(currentMinutes <= 60) currentMinutes = "00";
        mins--;
        document.getElementById("tMins").innerHTML = currentMinutes; 
        if(mins !== -1) setTimeout('Decrement()',10000);
    }
        function DecrementHours() {
        currentHours = Math.round(1440 / 60);
        if(currentHours <= 24) currentHours - 1;
        hours--;
        document.getElementById("tHours").innerHTML = currentHours; 
        if(hours !== -1) setTimeout('Decrement()',100000);
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is valid to bump a thread? If not, sorry, feel free to do what you must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved my own problem, but it's inelegant since it does not start at 24:00:00 but at 23:59:59. But it's a start.

I'll post it here in case it helps anyone

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 86400;
var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer() {
    count = count - 1;
    if (count == -1) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        return;
    }

    var seconds = count % 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    minutes %= 60;
    hours %= 60;

    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds; // watch for spelling
}
</script>



<span id='timer'></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The time in your intervals is wrong. You can try the code below. Just put thee vars in your html, like:

```
<span id='tHours'>23</span>:<span id='tMins'>59</span>:<span id='tSeconds'>59</span>:<span id='tMilli'>99</span>
```

And the js like:

```
var milli = 99;
var sec = 59;
var min = 59;
var hour = 23;

setInterval(function () {
    milli = milli == 0 ? 99 : milli - 1;
    $('#tMilli').text(double0(milli));
},10);

setInterval(function () {
    sec = sec == 0 ? 59 : sec - 1;
    $('#tSec').text(double0(sec));
},1000);

setInterval(function () {
    min = min == 0 ? 59 : min - 1;
    $('#tMin').text(double0(min));
},60000);

setInterval(function () {
    hour = hour == 0 ? 23 : hour - 1;
    $('#tHour').text(double0(hour));
},1440000);

function double0 (num) {
    num = num.toString().length == 1 ? '0' + num : num;
    return num;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Thalsan thanks to you I learned my mistake, I was using incorrect decreases indeed because I forgot that I wasn't working in single units of time anymore, duh! Im an idiot haha. However, your counter is not moving either. I assumed it was because the id's are different in your script from your html, but that wasn't it either. Thanks anyhow pal :)